# Best OCR practice for this kind of photo

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to design a program to read the digits on different meters using OpenCV and a raspberry pi.

I got something to work by creating a neural network for each meter digits, where I train manually. This method seems to have the highest accuracy so far.
I don't want to keep training a new neural network for every meter I need to read, (gas, water, electric, ect).
I have tried to use tesseract ocr, I wasn't really able to get an accurate reading on the digits.
FYI: I implemented a more basic way to read a 7seg display by detecting the elements on the 7 segment number. Only problem is it's not that easy to detect the contours of the box and perfectly find where the digits are, so I'm setting where are the digits manually and cropping that to use in my program.

Is there's libraries I can use to read numbers from a photo with high accuracy?
I considered using mnist data set to read the digits, but i'm not sure how accurate it is because it's made for handwritten numbers.

Any tips would be great.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think you need automatic or adaptive thresholding calibration to detect correct features. I hope alignment is taken care?

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to read an image using ocr (already cropped and threshed), I can handle the rest.

Comment: Tru easy ocr : https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR  it should work.